# Getting distance between two points within polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, proximity, point-in-polygon, polyline-creation

In QGIS 3.10 I have two layers, first one is point layer and the second one is polygon layer.

Every two points (with same `"ID"`) in my point layer overlay with a single polygon in polygon layer.

How do I get the minimum distance between 2 points in each polygon?

[image: Illustration]

Comment: What kind of output do you need, simply a number or a line with it's length or something different?

Comment: Just to get the distance (number in meter) between 2 points inside the polygon

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your two points have a common `"ID"` field, use this expression to create a new field with field calculator:

```
length (
    make_line (
        $geometry,
        geometry (
            get_feature (
                @layer,
                'ID',
                ID
))))
```

If you first have to create the `"ID"`, use `array_first(overlay_within('polygon', $id))` ([available since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core)).

*Points with same `"ID"` (labeled), connected with a line created on the basis of the above expression. With the expression above, you get the length of these lines:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir...your answer works! and I don't need the polygon layer because every two point already in same ID